# Bar edges are lighter, using Seaborn styles

Tags: jupyter-notebook, seaborn

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
sns.set_style("whitegrid")

%matplotlib inline

ys = [1, 3, 5, 9, 2, 1]
xs = range(len(ys))

plt.bar(xs, ys, color='w', edgecolor='black')
```

It produces:

[image]

What should I do to get really black bar edges, not the lighter version of them?

Of course, I can comment `sns.set()` and `sns.set_style("whitegrid")` to have default `matplotlib` style, where bar edges are black, but I want to solve it still using `seaborn`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm surmising a little here but from https://kristoformaynard.github.io/Viscid-docs/docs/master/styles/seaborn-whitegrid.html it looks as though the problem is in the axis.edgecolor attribute of this style. And from https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_style.html it seems as though the way to override it is to use the rc= parameter to 'set_style' which is a dictionary of the form {style_attribute : value}.